# Node js security: CORS, admin page and other things

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, security, cors

I am building my first node.js webapp. I don't need to manage users registrations. I just need an admin page wich easly allow updating the content of some pages.

I have almost finished the development phase but there is something about security I would like to clarify.

ADMIN PAGE: there are 2 level of security:

- 1) The admin page is linked to `mywebsite.com/hexadecimal_string` .
  Maybe it's very stupid but the admin page is a `"secret"` page. Linking
  it to `mywebsite.com/admin` is too much common. Do you think that using
  an hexadecimal string can be considered a first level of security?
- 2) Of course there is a password for admin, stored in my database. If
  the password is right, a temp cookie is setted. Maybe I should 
  encrtypt this password while is posted but I'm not planning to use
  https. Is there a way, different by using https, to make the posting
  of the password more secure ?

CORS: I don't need **CORS** but there is a thing that is making me crazy:

In the homepage everyone can post some data to server (we are talking about newsletter emails and others personal datas)
suppose someone reads the javascript code of the home page(in particular the ajax urls) in same way and he tries to post data to the same urls but using a personal script that skip the validation phase. Of course I did the validation to server also but I'd like to not accept any req coming from personal scripts written by other than me. The server should respond only to requests coming from my javascripts, tha anyone can run accessing to www.mywebsite.com. All other requests coming from different scripts will recieve `500-server error`.

Now, I read about lot's of people that is tryng to **ALLOW CORS**. So I was supposing that cors is disabled by default but I tried to post data from another website to mine and the data have been sent without problem and the server responds `200`. Why? Can I manage this thing?

There are other common things that I need to analyze and manage for security in my situation??

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use https and are looking for an alternative to that I presume you don't want the password to be sniffed in transit. I suggest a simple encryption decryption algorithm might work out for you. For the second issue, you can add a validation string which the client JS will pass along with other parameters while hitting your server API's. If you generate this string each time the client loads some specific page, then duplication of string will also be tackled.
In case you don't want at all to maintain any sort of db on server side, then attach a hidden HTML field to the API hits. This hidden field again you can encrypt and sent. If you broadcast this field periodically from the server, replication of the field will not be possible.

Also in CORS, you cannot request for data from a cross domain. CORS block comes in place when the browser gets a reply back from the server. Only posting of data does not cause any issue.

Comment: about cors: posting data will cause issue! Data will be added to my db and i don't want it! I want it only if the "post" came from my website. I repeat, i tried to post data from another website and my server do all inserts etc, as if the request was coming from my website. And the "second issue"?? i don't understand what you are pointing..

Comment: second issue is personal scripts inserting data in your db. For the same you can add a validation string or a hidden field when you call the Server API.